# Alexa programming 2 way communication

Tags: android, echo, alexa-skills-kit

We are building an Alexa skill that connects to a custom mobile application. As part of the skill we'd like to have a fallback intent that simply connects the user to an operator. The operator is using a custom mobile application (that we have already built).

Ideal order of operations:

1. Alexa converses with the user and cannot determine an intent
2. Alexa falls back to the fallback intent and says "Hold on, I am connecting you to an operator"
3. Alexa plays music and sends message to our existing system indicating that an operator should drop in on the smart speaker (in our case, we will be using an echo dot to start with).
4. Operator drops in on echo dot, at which point we terminate the hold music.
5. The operator can now manually determine the intent where Alexa was unable to.

I've been trying to figure out how to program this. Specifically:

- Is there any way to programmatically drop in on a device (using a deviceId)?
- In general, how does one push notifications to the Alexa enabled device. For example in #4, we would need to enable a drop in intercom type functionality but also ensure that the music is terminated at that point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have a far easier time not recreating the wheel, I would look into accomplishing your Amazon Connect, utilizing Lex and the hand over via established routines already build into Amazon Connect service.

Comment: @ChuckLaPress Yeah, I definitely don't want to recreate the wheel. Not sure that Amazon connect is the solution though. We have an app already, we'd like to enable users to communicate through their echo dot (or similar smart speaker) with the operator that is logged into the app. Any good prebuilt solutions for this?

Comment: Look at Lex and connecting the bot via an iframe to your application, Lex is capable of the switching intents, and providing your communications are simple it's capable of voice interactions with text as a fallback. Alexa just is the wrong platform for your use case.

Comment: @ChuckLaPress The problem is that we need to have the user communicate via a speaker... we have an app for the operator but the user has no app.